# quero criar um struct de tamanho variavel e o programa da erro

Tags: c++, struct

eu estou tentando criar um struct de tamanho variável porem sempre q faço isso na segunda execução do loop o programa trava

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct produto{
    int codProd,quantProd;
    float precoProd;
    char nomeProd[6];
};
main(){
    int opcao,codigo,quantVend,y;
    produto roupas[y];
    y = 3;
    do{
        printf("1 cadastro\n");
        printf("2 vendas\n");
        printf("3 relatorio\n");
        printf("4 preco\n");
        printf("0 sair\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        if(opcao == 1){
            printf("digite a quantidade de produtos que vai registrar\n");
            scanf("%d",&y);
            for(int x=0;x<y;x++){
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("codigo");
                scanf("%d",&roupas[x].codProd);
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("nome do produto:");
                gets(roupas[x].nomeProd);
                printf("quantidade:");
                scanf("%d",&roupas[x].quantProd);
                printf("preco :");
                scanf("%f",&roupas[x].precoProd);

            }
        }
        if(opcao == 3){
            printf("relatorio do estoque\n");
            for(int x=0;x<y;x++){
                printf("codigo: %d\n",roupas[x].codProd);
                printf("nome do produto: %s\n",roupas[x].nomeProd);
                printf("quantidade: %d\n",roupas[x].quantProd);

            }
        }
        if(opcao == 2){
            printf("vendas\n");
            printf("digite o codigo do produto \n");
            scanf("%d",&codigo);
            for(int x=0;x<y;x++){
                if(codigo == roupas[x].codProd){
                    printf("voce vendeu :%s\n",roupas[x].nomeProd);
                    roupas[x].quantProd = roupas[x].quantProd - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }while(opcao=!0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que está usando a variável antes de inicializar

```
int opcao,codigo,quantVend,y; //Cria a variável y
produto roupas[y]; //Usa a variável y
y = 3; //Atribui um valor a variável y
```

A ordem deve ser essa

```
int opcao,codigo,quantVend,y; //Cria a variável y
y = 3; //Atribui um valor a variável y
produto roupas[y]; //Usa a variável y
```

Comment: Entendi, teria alguma forma de eu atribuir o valor dessa variavel depois de ter utilizado ela ? Eu estou precisando disso prara um sistema de cadastro de produtos

Comment: Não, mas por que tu precisa usar antes de inicializar?

Comment: Talvez alocação dinâmica de memória ajude na solução de seu problema. Pesquise pela função malloc.

Comment: Se estivesse realmente utilizando C++ era só utliizar o new.

Comment: Guilherme eu preciso usar antes porque eu quero que o usuario decida o tamanho da struct so para o sistrma funcionar eu preciso declarar a struct antes de dar a opcao pro usuario escolher o tamanho dela

Comment: Da uma revisada no teu código, você quer uma coisa mas parece que está faendo outra